# Retrieving JSON Object Literal from HttpServletRequest

Tags: json, post, servlets

I am writing code that needs to extract an object literal posted to a servlet. I have studied the API for the HttpServletRequest object, but it is not clear to me how to get the JSON object out of the request since it is not posted from a form element on a web page.

Comment: Your question is confusing. Please show the JavaScript code (or whatever it might be) that causes something to be POSTed to the servlet, if it isn't a form. If you're looking for some built-in J2EE method to understand JSON object literals, there is none.

Comment: Is your problem that you are trying to send a json object from the browser to the servlet, and you can't get the information on the servlet?

Comment: See also more popular http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3831680/httpservletrequest-get-post-data

Answer (score 68):

are you looking for this ?

```
@Override
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    BufferedReader reader = request.getReader();
    try {
        String line;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line).append('\n');
        }
    } finally {
        reader.close();
    }
    System.out.println(sb.toString());
}
```

Comment: This method do convert json representation into a string, but I think it is probably not the best way to handle json data.

Answer (score 59):

This is simple method to get request data from `HttpServletRequest`
using **Java 8 Stream API**:

```java
String requestData = request.getReader().lines().collect(Collectors.joining());
```

Comment: This deserves more attention! Simplest solution in my opinion.

Comment: I get `java.lang.IllegalStateException: STREAMED` when calling `getReader()`. Any tips ?

Comment: from inside `org.eclipse.jetty.server.Request`

Answer (score 44):

make use of the jackson JSON processor

```
 ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
  Book book = mapper.readValue(request.getInputStream(),Book.class);
```

Comment: This is perfect! You rock!

Comment: @Clyde D'Cruz How to use this while using HttpExchange..??

Comment: Work for me well<3

Answer (score 31):

The easiest way is to populate your bean would be from a Reader object, this can be done in a single call:

```
BufferedReader reader = request.getReader();
Gson gson = new Gson();

MyBean myBean = gson.fromJson(reader, MyBean.class);
```

Answer (score 23):

There is another way to do it, using `org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils` to extract the String from the request

```
String jsonString = IOUtils.toString(request.getInputStream());
```

Then you can do whatever you want, convert it to `JSON` or other object with `Gson`, etc.

```
JSONObject json = new JSONObject(jsonString);
MyObject myObject = new Gson().fromJson(jsonString, MyObject.class);
```

Comment: IOUtils.toString is Deprecated 
I used 

"String jsonString = new String(ByteStreams.toByteArray(request.getInputStream()))"

Comment: @Lelis718 this post is from 2015 and the question from 2009, stuff gets old

Comment: @Lelis718 The JavaDocs for the deprecated method offer [`IOUtils.toString(InputStream input, Charset charset)`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/IOUtils.html#toString(java.io.InputStream,java.nio.charset.Charset)) as  replacement. This method buffers the input internally, so there is no need to use a `BufferedInputStream` etc. So essentially it is the same method as previous, the only difference is that it has one more parameter - `Charset charset`.

Answer (score 5):

If you're trying to get data out of the request body, the code above works. But, I think you are having the same problem I was..

If the data in the body is in JSON form, and you want it as a Java object, you'll need to parse it yourself, or use a library like [google-gson](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson) to handle it for you. You should look at the docs and examples at the project's website to know how to use it. It's fairly simple.

Answer (score 0):

Converting the retreived data from the request object to json object is as below using google-gson

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
ABCClass c1 = gson.fromJson(data, ABCClass.class);

//ABC class is a class whose strcuture matches to the data variable retrieved
```

Comment: Did you test this? It doesn't work. java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: class 'HttpServletRequest' declares multiple JSON fields named 'logger'.

Answer (score 0):

Use following dependencies

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
   <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
   <version>2.10.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Version can be any latest version

We can process Json input with following line of code

```
BufferedReader reader = request.getReader();
Gson gson = new Gson();
MyBean myBean = gson.fromJson(reader, MyBean.class);
```