# Angular JS & Spring REST -How to Convert JSON Model object to HttpServletRequest for a legacy app

Tags: java, angularjs, spring-mvc, servlets, spring-rest

I need to work on an enterprise legacy Java application that is developed in servlets & jsp's.Planning to convert this legacy app to a Single Page application using angular js & Spring MVC REST.

In the new development, AngularJS will be submitting the model object's (as JSON ) to Spring REST methods.

In the existing application there is a lot of code in servlets and classes (at least 2000 lines in 30 classes) written to get request parameter's using `HttpServletRequest` i.e., `request.getParameter("name");`

Is it possible to be able to inject/convert the model (JSON) object submitted by angularJs to Spring MVC REST methods into `HttpServletRequest` object, so that I need not change all the legacy code & classes?

Not considering to use the `@RequestParam` annotation in the method signature as the number of parameters are high.

Comment: does this help maybe? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1548782/retrieving-json-object-literal-from-httpservletrequest

Comment: if I understand correctly it's possible, but if you can provide some example of requested JSON and expected mapping to HttpServletRequest it will be helpful.

Comment: @levgen - Mapping will be in similar lines as posted by Viral in the response.                                                                                                                                                                                                                         Is it possible to convert data from model i.e., "UIData" in example posted by VIral to HttpServletRequest?

Comment: One option is to retrieve the data from model object and set it into request as attributes : request.setAttribute("AttributeName",value)

Answer (score 0):

Whatever JSON Object you are defining like below and which you trying to pass backend

```
var dataToPass={
    name:"XYZ",
    id:12,
    selstat:[12,14]
};
```

For that, you need to create JAVA POJO with similar name  like below

```
class UIData{
 private String name; // Getter and Setter
 private Integer id; // Getter and Setter
 private List<Integer> selstat; // Getter and Setter
}
```

And in Spring while defining mapping in controller, you need to use annotation @ResuestBody in argument like below

```
@RequestMapping(value ='/mappingURL', method = RequestMethod.POST)
        public @ResponseBody RsponseObject processData(@RequestBody UIData uiData, HttpServletRequest request) 
            throws MyException {

                // Process you data
            }
```

This will automatically convert JSON object into POJO instance.

Please go through Spring  Documentation for more details.

And make sure content-type in header while passing is **application/json** along with Jackson library added in your dependency.

Comment: Thanks Viraj for the response with code sample. I am trying to find a way to be able to convert data from model i.e., "UIData" in above example to HttpServletRequest , so that I need not change all the legacy code that is retrieving data from HttpServletRequest  object.