# JSON RAW REQUEST in controller

Tags: json, spring-mvc

I have the code as below

```
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public @ResponseBody ServiceResponse submitCustomerOrder(@RequestBody SubmitCustomerOrderRequest submitCustomerOrderRequest,HttpServletRequest request)
    {
     String json=????
    }
```

I need the de-serialization  should happen to **SubmitCustomerOrderRequest** object but also need the raw json request in  the string for logging the request purpose.

Can anybody help me on this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Retrieving JSON Object Literal from HttpServletRequest](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1548782/retrieving-json-object-literal-from-httpservletrequest)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use google's Gson library

```
log.info(new Gson().toJson(submitCustomerOrderRequest))
```

Comment: Sorry I don't want that as it will take marshaling time