# Java Servlet not accepting application/json post requests

Tags: java, json, servlets

I have developer a Java Servlet that works well with application/javascript requests such as:

```
curl -H "application/javascript" -X POST -d "action=register_user" http://example.com/api/users
```

I want it to accept application/json as well, because in the request below the servlet cannot detect any parameters

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d '{"action":"register_user"}' http://example.com/api/users
```

How can I modify the servlet below to make it work with application/json?

```
public class Manage extends HttpServlet {

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
     */
    public Manage() {
    }

    public Manage(Server server) {
        super();
    }   

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        String action = request.getParameter("action");
        dosomething(action);
    }
```

Comment: What does the javadoc of `getParameter` say?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Retrieving JSON Object Literal from HttpServletRequest](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1548782/retrieving-json-object-literal-from-httpservletrequest)

Comment: Previously, you POSTed a http post variable with the name "action". You don't do that anymore, which is why ``request.getParameter("action")`` will return ``null``.

Comment: @f1sh what do you mean? In the second request I am sending a JSON with attribute "action". How can I modify the servlet in order to capture it?